# submit ajax request on keyboard ENTER

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have on click jquery that submits ajax request.

There are no forms.

I'd like keyboard ENTER to be used also to submit ajax request.

I've allot of these buttons, this confuses me as I cannot simply do:

```
$('#myForm input:text').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $("#button1").click()
  }
});
```

My currect on click event looks like this (how do I extend this to accomodate ENTER?)

```
//Check answer
$("body").on("click", ".unlocked figcaption .check", function(){
    var logo_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var answer = $("#" + logo_id + " input[name=guesslogo]");
    var logo_lang = answer.attr("data-lang");

    answer.removeAttr("class").attr("disabled","true");

        //Submit answer for review
        $.ajax({
            url: "actions.php",
            get: "GET",
            data: "answer=" + answer.val() + "&logo_id=" + logo_id + "&logo_lang=" + logo_lang,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data){
                var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (response.result == 1) {
                    answer.addClass("correct").siblings(".clear, .hint").fadeTo("slow","0.4");
                    answer.parent().append('<div class="alert"><h3>Correct!</h3> <p>Score: '+ response.score +'</p></div>');
                    $("#" + logo_id).siblings(".logo").removeClass("logo").addClass("answered").removeAttr("style");
                    snd_correct.play();
                        //update user_score and user_level values in leaderboard and header widgets
                        var this_user = $("header aside").attr("data-usern");
                        if (this_user) {
                            var this_user_score = $("header aside .user_score").text();
                            var this_user_level = $("header aside .user_level").text();
                                $("[data-usern="+ this_user +"] .user_score").empty().append(parseInt(this_user_score) + parseInt(response.score));
                                if (response.level_up == 1) {
                                    var new_level = parseInt(this_user_level) +1;
                                    $("[data-usern="+ this_user +"] .user_level").empty().append(new_level);
                                    update_view(new_level);
                                }
                            //
                            update_level_progress_bar();
                        }
                } else if (response.result == 0) {
                    answer.addClass("wrong").removeAttr("disabled");
                    snd_wrong.play();
                } else if (response.result == 2) {
                    answer.addClass("almost").removeAttr("disabled");
                    snd_wrong.play();
                }
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

I uploaded sample here: http://gamoicani.es/logo/ click on any logo, I'd like to use keyboard ENTER also to submit.

Comment: Why can't you do `$('#myForm input:text').keypress`? Are they all not text inputs? Is there a click event handler for the `#button1`?

Comment: This certainly sounds like something that the .keypress function should be used for... You might need to add `e.preventDefault();` into your keypress function before the `button.click()` call.

Comment: what will `$(this).parent()` return

Comment: also please share a markup sample

Comment: @ArunPJohny Hi, you can see it in action here: http://gamoicani.es/logo/

Comment: Usally pressing enter in a text input by default submits a `<form>` - you don't need to listen for keypress events. Don't you listen for `submit` already?

Comment: @Bergi I don't have a form.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze: Then get one. Every `<input>` should be part of a `<form>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the ajax function external and then call it on click and keypress (enter) events like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".unlocked figcaption .check", ajaxFunction);
$(document).on("keypress", "#myForm input:text", function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13){
      e.preventDefault();
      ajaxFunction();
  }
});

function ajaxFunction(){
    var logo_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var answer = $("#" + logo_id + " input[name=guesslogo]");
    var logo_lang = answer.attr("data-lang");

    answer.removeAttr("class").attr("disabled","true");

        //Submit answer for review
        $.ajax({
            url: "actions.php",
            get: "GET",
            data: "answer=" + answer.val() + "&logo_id=" + logo_id + "&logo_lang=" + logo_lang,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data){
                var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (response.result == 1) {
                    answer.addClass("correct").siblings(".clear, .hint").fadeTo("slow","0.4");
                    answer.parent().append('<div class="alert"><h3>Correct!</h3> <p>Score: '+ response.score +'</p></div>');
                    $("#" + logo_id).siblings(".logo").removeClass("logo").addClass("answered").removeAttr("style");
                    snd_correct.play();
                        //update user_score and user_level values in leaderboard and header widgets
                        var this_user = $("header aside").attr("data-usern");
                        if (this_user) {
                            var this_user_score = $("header aside .user_score").text();
                            var this_user_level = $("header aside .user_level").text();
                                $("[data-usern="+ this_user +"] .user_score").empty().append(parseInt(this_user_score) + parseInt(response.score));
                                if (response.level_up == 1) {
                                    var new_level = parseInt(this_user_level) +1;
                                    $("[data-usern="+ this_user +"] .user_level").empty().append(new_level);
                                    update_view(new_level);
                                }
                            //
                            update_level_progress_bar();
                        }
                } else if (response.result == 0) {
                    answer.addClass("wrong").removeAttr("disabled");
                    snd_wrong.play();
                } else if (response.result == 2) {
                    answer.addClass("almost").removeAttr("disabled");
                    snd_wrong.play();
                }
            }
        });

    return false;
};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/yfNQb/)

Comment: Can anyone explain why: $("body").on("keypress", "input:text[name=guesslogo]", function(){
 console.dir(this);
}); triggers only on first input? The subsequent events don't care...

Comment: it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/8M6YH/ ! is your js code loaded in head or body section?

Answer (score 3):

// Try this!! :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).on('keypress click','.unlocked figcaption .check',function(e){
    if((e.type === 'keypress' && e.keyCode === 13) || e.type === 'click')
    {
       // All your code inside the .on()
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me, $("body").on("keypress", "input:text[name=guesslogo]", function(){
 console.dir(this);
}); why this triggers only on first input? the rest don't care?

Comment: I wouldn't personally use $('body').on("keypress","input blah

I would us the selector for the input:

$('input:text[name=blah]').bind('keypress',function(){

ajaxFunction();

Comment: and then the event for the click. Just trying to understand your question a bit more. Why you using $.on() out of interest??

I tend to use binds more due to multiple events firing different code and then single out the differences by a simple check of the current event type

Event/Handler/Logic separation is a good habit to get into similar to how rassak has done. I tend to use jQuery as intended though, I only really separate if I coding in raw js

Comment: you are the best cjonasw